# Four "Publicist" badges awarded during single week?

Tags: discussion, badges

Getting the `Publicist` gold badge sounds as an extremely hard to achieve task. You need to share a link to question or an answer, that will be visited by at least 1000 unique IP addresses. There are [*nearly three and a half million* users here](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) and [**only 444 of them** has received this badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/262/publicist) so far. That's around 0.01 percent of entire community.

Basing on these numbers, isn't that a little bit odd, that one person  has been awarded four times during past week with this badge, where three of four of that awards happened during only 2 days?

I'm a total newbie to probability and statistics. Just to feed my curiosity, can anyone calculate chances for a single user to receive four `Publicist` badges during one week (or three of them during two days), if only 444 of three and a half million users managed to receive it during five or more years of Stack Overflow existence?

Comment: Any reason why this couldn't have been communicated to the moderators and/or the community team instead of publicly?

Comment: Yes: (1) I'm not aware of any rule that forces me to keep such things secret, (2) as in introduction: I don't think, this is any spoiler and I hope this is just a good luck of this user and (3) I don't know how to comunicate with moderators on such thing (badge, user, not a post).

Comment: Maybe each of those 1000+ viewers also looked those other 3 questions asked by him :)

Comment: There is a "contact us" link at the bottom of every page on the network. Or  flag just about anything of yourself or the user in question and use the "other" option to explain your concerns.

Comment: The publicist badge is very easy to get if you have either a popular blog or you post to Reddit/Hacker News. That said, doing it too much will be seen as spam in those communities. (and it has happened before)

Comment: You went off with a (possible) accusation of someone - keeping it private would have been the _nice_ thing to do. Personally - if you are going to point fingers at someone, starting off with a public accusation is not the way to go.

Comment: Or flag it and exclude the name / user profile from this meta post as it could be interesting to discuss these probabilities but it's not necessary to include the user's name in this public post.

Comment: OK, I see your point and I understand, what I did wrong. I'm sorry for that. What steps should be done next by me? Since this was _communicated_ to moderators, and have some privacy problems, maybe I just delete this post?

Comment: There are a lot of people in the list which got the badge multiple times, I even found users with 17 and 31. Some of these were awarded a few minutes apart from each other for the same user. So, it seems nothing special if your talking in terms of statistics.

Comment: @Oded I don't see an accusation or a named party anywhere in the question. This is a part of the site's mechanics and behavior that the public deserves to know about.

Comment: @TylerH - it was edited out. OP posted a link to the "offending" profile.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid Please, read my question again and read how to gain this particular badge. There is absolutely no comaprison between getting other badges (even many times, even in short period of time) and this particular one, as it requires much work to be done. Look again at the statistics, you don't like so much in my question. If only 444 users out of 3,5M has gained this particular badge in period of five or more years, then it should be obvious, that it is extremely hard to get it. And getting three of them during two days _may sound suspicious_ (may = I don't say, it is).

Comment: @trejder with all respect, your conclusion is incorrect. It is not extremly hard to get, it just requires a little effort and time will do the rest. Look through the list of badges and you'll notice that there a 444 badges distributed over a lot less than 444 users. Many (if not most) users received the badge multiple times, up to whopping 31 times. There are also more users who have earned 2-4 badges in a short amount of time.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid Ah, now I see your point! :> Thanks for elaboration...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I got my two publicist badges by posting links to the questions on Reddit. Easy as that. I'm not a badge whore but just wanted to see if it was possible, and it definitely was. I didn't feel like the Reddit community appreciated my posts very much, but a lot of people clicked on the links none the less.

So no, I don't think it's anything out of the ordinary to get four publicist badges within a week.

Comment: Ditto with Reddit, 1000 people really isn't that many people on the internet

Comment: I've also linked a few posts on Reddit/HN, and all of them were appreciated, at least in the sense of sparking interesting discussions.

Comment: Yup. For a while I stayed up top of [the most publicist badges list](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/200147/most-publicist-badges-awarded) by just submitting new links to Reddit whenever Bill the Lizard got too close. (I eventually lost commitment, and he's pulled way ahead.)

Comment: This is where I "reveal" that this was my plan all along! I suggested in SE Podcast #16 that they encourage more activity on those badges, which led to them being made earnable multiple times, which let me inflate my gold badge count to unreasonable levels. You may now redirect your "badge whore" complaints away from Klaus.

Comment: @JeremyBanks I did it for the reddit karma. ;)

Answer (score 7):

Maybe that individual just has a very large following in the programming community

(Think about Jon Skeet).

Comment: Jon Skeet doesn't actually have any Publicist badges.

Comment: Surprising. I suppose he doesn't share much, however he was just a person of note to make my point.

Comment: I remember [Joel Spolsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky) saying that on the podcast once, years ago. Every time he mentions a question on Twitter, he logs into SO to find a Publicist badge.

Comment: Clearly that was hyperbole though, because [he's only got two of them :-)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky?tab=badges) Or he did it exactly twice.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski For reference, that was [Stack Exchange Podcast Episode 16](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/se-podcast-16/).

Comment: @JeremyBanks Nice dive. I didn't have the wherewithal to actually look for it :)